VBA Floating Instructions
I am trying to create a floating message or a helper message, so people know what to input in a formula when they call my function.
this is the message I mean:

Where it says: logical}_test, [value_if_true]. ][value_if_false])
I need to create this for my function.
This is my function:
Option Explicit

Public Function POtracker(POtofind As String, Optional fOption As Byte, Optional sOption As Byte) As String
    
    POtofind 'The PO you want to return information about
    fOption 'Type 1 for: return "Yes" or "No", type 2 for: return "Text" or "Location (Address)"
    sOption 'Type 0 to look for a similar match or whole for full match.
    
End Function

